# Looking for more efficiency in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a web app/game that has a ton of clickable .png images that glow when you hover over them and change even further momentarily when clicked.  The code I have currently does exactly what I want it to do, but I'm noticing that there are a lot of redundancies going out and getting elements by ID.  I'm wondering if maybe someone with more javascript savvy than me knows of a better way to write this. Naturally, in the root folder there are 3 .png files for every "button", each representing the pic in different states...(i.e. inventorypic.png, inventorypicglow.png, and inventorypicdown.png would be the image files that get changed in and out of the DOM depending on the status of the "inventorypic" element.)

```
function glowText(element) {
    var glowPicName = element.id +  "glow.png";
    element.src = glowPicName;
}
function normalText(element) {
    var normalPicName = element.id + ".png";
    element.src = normalPicName;
}
function downText(element) {
    var downPicName = element.id + "down.png";
    element.src = downPicName;
}
document.getElementById("inventorypic").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("inventorypic").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){normalText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("inventorypic").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){downText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("inventorypic").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){glowText(this)}, false);

document.getElementById("refinementpic").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("refinementpic").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){normalText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("refinementpic").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){downText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("refinementpic").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){glowText(this)}, false);

document.getElementById("propertiespic").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("propertiespic").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){normalText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("propertiespic").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){downText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("propertiespic").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){glowText(this)}, false);

document.getElementById("locationpic").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("locationpic").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){normalText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("locationpic").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){downText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("locationpic").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){glowText(this)}, false);

document.getElementById("descriptionpic").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("descriptionpic").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){normalText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("descriptionpic").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){downText(this)}, false);
document.getElementById("descriptionpic").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
```

There are a lot more of these 4-line blocks (I just didn't copy them all here).. one for each button and it's getting kind of ridiculous looking. Is there a better way to do this?

I have one other smaller question that I think I already know the answer to but I just want to check anyway... Can you make elements in custom shapes, as in a shape other than a square or rectangle?  I think no, but tell me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try get object once by ID, and then use reference.

```
var inventorypic = document.getElementById("inventorypic");
addEvents(inventorypic);    

var refinementpic= document.getElementById("refinementpic");
addEvents(refinementpic); 

var propertiespic = document.getElementById("propertiespic");
addEvents(propertiespic );   

var descriptionpic= document.getElementById("descriptionpic");
addEvents(descriptionpic);    

fucntion addEvents(obj)
{
    obj.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
    obj.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){normalText(this)}, false);
    obj.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){downText(this)}, false);
    obj.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){glowText(this)}, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fahad, that helps a lot.